# Ler arquivo em pasta anterior python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

então estou querendo salvar um arquvio python numa pasta anterior ao que está rodando o script

ex:meu script esta no diretorio /app/controllers/script.py
eu quero colocar o arquivo que eu vou criar na pasta: /app/statics/download/arq.zip

codigo:

```py
import os.path
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

localsalvar = basedir + '../statics/downloads/'
with open(localsalvar + id + '.zip', "w") as f:
    f.write(cvcompacto)#criando o arquivo .zip
```

Ele nao ta conseguindo subir de pasta, ta achando que o '/../' é uma pasta

```py
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/extrator/app/controllers../statics/downloads/9837509907462335.zip'
```

Comment: Lucas, já tentou colocar apenas o valor '../static/downloads/' sem concatenar o basedir?

Comment: Sim sim da o mesmo problema
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../statics/downloads/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No caminho da mensagem de erro

```
'/root/extrator/app/controllers../statics/downloads/9837509907462335.zip'
```

está aparentemente faltando um separador de diretórios (barra) entre `'controllers'` e `'..'` - seu sistema está procurando por uma pasta chamada `'controllers..'`, que provavelmente não existe.

Modifique a linha

```
localsalvar = basedir + '../statics/downloads/'
```

para

```
localsalvar = basedir + '/../statics/downloads/'
```

ou melhor ainda, utilize `os.path.join` para que seu código adicione os separadores automaticamente (funcionando tanto para Windows quanto para Mac e Linux):

```
localsalvar = os.path.join(basedir, '..', 'statics', 'downloads')
```

Comment: Então ele continua o mesmo erro, ele ta entendendo que o '..' é o nome de uma pasta


```python
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/extrator/app/controllers/../statics/downloads/9837509907462335.zip'
```

Comment: Por favor confirme que o diretório `'/root/extrator/app/statics/downloads/` existe no seu computador. O caminho parece válido, portanto a única forma de gerar este erro é se o diretório não existir.

Answer (score 0):

No Python, para mover um arquivo para outro diretório basta usar o módulo shutil:

```
import shutil
shutil.move("cvcompacto", "/../statics/downloads/")
```